# How to edit the features block in a .VMCX file (the new Hyper V config binaries)?

Tags: xml, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v, steam

I am attempting to make use of the Hyper V API to make changes to a virtual machine file.

Previously, when Hyper V relied on XLM files for configuration, the change in question would amount to straightforward changes in the features block. Once example of this is setting the Hyper V mode to "passthrough" as follows

```
<features>　
  <hyperv mode='passthrough'>
    <!-- 。。。-->
  </hyperv>
  <!-- 。。。-->
<features>
```

... or, say, pass a vendor_id as follows

```
<features>　
  <hyperv>
    <!-- 。。。-->
    <vendor_id state='on' value='0123'/>
  </hyperv>
  <!-- 。。。-->
<features>
```

A Microsoft engineer does talk about editing these files in a [blogpost here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/editing-a-vmcx-file), accompanied by [this code sample](https://gist.github.com/BenjaminArmstrong/1a8d6531231ee020c67d752df63029f1).

However, I was unable to decrypt the documentation. Does anyone now how one could go about implementing changes functionally equivalent to those described above for XML?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at 2nd link lines 7 to 12 which are the parameters and vmcx file.  Then locate these variables in the code to see how to modify these parameters.  It is very simple.

Comment: Yes, it is. And if the question were about params instead of features, that would be relevant.

Comment: What is the differences?  Feature is a windows option that is the name of the xml tag.  You are trying to change parameters.